# NodeJS connect to wss on another server

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

There is a wss on another server that I'd like to connect to. Let's say its address is: wss://123.123.123.12:8843

I have a nodejs/expressjs app. How do I connect to it using socket.io? I know how to implement socket.io for a server/client setup, but how do I do it for two servers (one of which I don't have access to).

How do I setup my expressjs app to connect to the wss? Is there a way using socket.io or do I need to do it another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Socket.IO isn't a WebSocket. It is a transport system that supports WebSockets, but if you want to interface with other WebSockets, you'd have better luck using the [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) module, which Socket.IO uses internally. This is how it's used:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');
ws.on('open', function() {
    ws.send('something');
});
ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
    // flags.binary will be set if a binary data is received
    // flags.masked will be set if the data was masked
});
```

If you actually just want to communicate with another Socket.IO server, then install the client on the server. It's used the same way as you would use with a browser client.

```
npm install socket.io-client
```

And then usage:

```
var socket = require('socket.io')('http://host/path');
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.on('event', function(data) { });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() { });
});
```

Comment: Good to know. After trying einaros' ws (https://github.com/einaros/ws), I keep getting the error SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN. I'm trying to run this on a Mac.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.10.20.

Comment: Node.js v0.10+ is automatically configured to reject SSL certificates that are self-signed. To fix this, set the environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to `0`.

Comment: How we can handle the error if websocket server is not responding  correctly to "ws" npm module. This is stopping my server.

error is like  "uncaughtException connect ECONNREFUSED"

Comment: How many websocket client object can I create?